# Сделать выборку после передачи формы, ajax, serialize

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Подскадите пожалуйста как сделать выборку на основе полученных данных. Передаю данные в обработчик:

```
$("#filter__form").on( "submit", function( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          let filter_data = $(this).serialize();

          $.ajax({
                url: '/filter.php',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {filter: filter_data},
                success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Получаю данные в таком виде

```
 f__vid=&f__material=&f__material=%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE&f__price=&f__ves=16.18&f__ves=4.01&f__ves=3.98&f__ves=2.33&f__ves=16.38&f__ves=2.56&f__ves=1.4&f__vstavka=&f__proba=
```

Подскажите плиз как сделать выборку из базы на основе этих данных?

Answer (score 0):

1. Получаете данные в php файле

   ```php
   $get_vid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['f__vid']); // не забываем экранировать
   ```
2. Средствами php делает запрос в своей БД, типа (входные данные должны быть экранированы, см. п.1):

   ```sql
   SELECT FROM MY_TABLE WHERE vid=$_POST['f__vid'] AND material=$_POST['f__material'] AND price=$_POST['f__price'] AND ves=$_POST['f__ves'] AND vstavka=$_POST['f__vstavka'] AND  proba=$_POST['f__proba'];
   ```